# htaccess lang prefix and query string

Tags: .htaccess

i have an htaccess that add a lang prefix on a specific folder on all files

htaccess rules

```
RewriteRule ^fr/folder/(.*)$                /folder/$1?lang=1 [L]
RewriteRule ^en/folder/(.*)$                /folder/$1?lang=2 [L]
```

With the above rules i can redirect the

```
/en/folder/myscript.php to /folder/myscript.php?lang=1
```

and its working fine.

Now i am trying to find a way to add the query string if any

for example

```
/en/folder/myscript.php?id=100 to /folder/myscript.php?lang=1&id=100
```

I have try to use the code below but no luck

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^lang=1
RewriteRule ^el/folder/(.*)$                /folder/$1?lang=1&%1 [L]
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).

If you use

```
RewriteRule ^fr/folder/(.*)$                /folder/$1?lang=1 [L, QSA]
RewriteRule ^en/folder/(.*)$                /folder/$1?lang=2 [L, QSA]
```

The query string shouldn't be overwritten.

Comment: Can you tell, how to do it in any directoy?